# RAM upgrade compatibility for HP Elite 8300 Desktop

Tags: memory, upgrade, ddr3

I have a HP Elite 8300 PC.

https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-compaq-elite-8300-ultra-slim-pc/5232866/document/c03345460

It already has an 4GB x 2 RAM installed. The specification of the RAM already installed are

`4GB 1Rx8 PC3L-12800U-11-12-A1`  from `Kingston`

I want to upgrade the RAM on the machine. I have an 8GB RAM  and a 4GB RAM with me with the following specification.

`8GB DDR3L-1600 UDIMM 1.35V CL11` from `Crucial by Micron`
`4GB 2Rx8 PC3-10600U-09-11-B1` from `Samsung`.

I tried inserting both of these.It didn't work. I message that I got was something like, `RAM error - The size of the RAM during the last reboot was different` and it didn't boot up.

I want to know if the 8GB RAM is compatible with my HP Desktop

Comment: According to the document, the PC only support 1600Mhz RAM while the 4GB RAM (PC3-10600S) only runs at 1333Mhz (can be a issue). About the error it's weird, maybe try to clear the CMOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 
[HP Compaq Business PC Maintenance and Service Guide Elite 8300 Series](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03612798)
specifies these memory sticks:

[image]

And has these warnings:

[image]

Therefore DDR3L is not supported, and also PC3-10600U.
Your two RAM sticks are just not compatible.

If you are buying Crucial RAM, use their
[scanner tool](https://www.crucial.com/)
to find guaranteed compatible RAM.